# Make cnext and cprevious loop back to the begining

Tags: quickfix

If I run `:cnext` when I'm already at the end of the quickfix list I get the error message

```
E553: No more items
```

and nothing happens. Instead of this, when I enter `:cnext` at the end of the list, I would like vim to cycle back around to the first quickfix entry. Is it possible configure vim for this behavior?

Comment: Already answered many times in the past.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27198612/4959010)'s one example.

Answer (score 21):

You can write some commands:

```
command! Cnext try | cnext | catch | cfirst | catch | endtry
command! Cprev try | cprev | catch | clast | catch | endtry

command! Lnext try | lnext | catch | lfirst | catch | endtry
command! Lprev try | lprev | catch | llast | catch | endtry
```

If the exception is caught, it jumps to the first/last item.  You can use `cabbrev` so you don't have to use the upper case commands:

```
cabbrev cnext Cnext
cabbrev cprev CPrev
cabbrev lnext Lnext
cabbrev lprev Lprev
```